# Linking firebase accounts, JSON and images together

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I have uploaded my image to the firebase database easily enough using this code:

```
uploadImageButton.addEventListener('change', function(e){
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var storageRef = storage.ref('pictures/' + file.name)
  var task = storageRef.put(file);
})
```

I was wondering how to link this to a particular user I have stored in my JSON, or to a user I have in my accounts?

When I sign up a user I want to be able to store an image and there auth account and retrieve them whenever I wish.

So far I can retrieve the relevant JSON, but not the auth account or images.

[image: my json]

Answer (score 0):

For that you just create a folder with the user UID and place the file inside that folder.

```
uploadImageButton.addEventListener('change', function(e){
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  var storageRef = storage.ref('pictures/' + UID +'/' + file.name)
  var task = storageRef.put(file);
})
```

Here UID is the userid corresponding to the account.

use the folowing code to get the download url:

```
task.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){ 
  var url = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;

  var updates = {};
  updates['users/'+ UID +'/profile_image'] = url;
  firebase.database().ref().update(updates);
}
```

Now you are setting the download url in profile_image property.

Comment: that's what I thought but when I retrieve it will it definitely retrieve it correctly?

Comment: Yes. I just edited the answer .. please check it.. Place 'state_changed' inside the  'change' listener

Comment: @TheCalculator Did you solved the issue? Is my code helps you ?